# can i change my docusign account type from production to sandbox?

Tags: docusignapi

I have already signed up with docusign normally using my email address. But i realize i should've signed up with the developer sandbox instead. Now when i try to sign up in https://secure.docusign.com/signup/develop using the same email address, it says "*An account with this email already exists*" - I can't sign up for the developer sandbox.

What do I change to the developer sandbox for the same email address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the SignUp screen go ahead and click the activate button even though the validation message says the email address already exists. It should create an account in the Sandbox.

Make sure you start at https://demo.docusign.net for creating accounts in sandbox.

Comment: Nice solution. Worked.